# Does executing "ntpd -q" while running an active NTPD alter the kernel discipline? How would I check if it was changed? Suse linux

Tags: settings, ntp, suse, changeset, ntpd

I accidentally ran "ntpd -q" on a suse box and I am not sure if this just updated the time or if it changes how the daemon actually runs. How would I check this? There was an active ntpd running at the time.

Ran command by accident. Did not want to make any changes to the daemon.

Answer (score 0):

If there was already a `ntpd` process running, the command will do nothing. That already running process did already tweak the kernel, depending on how it was configured.